# Twilio not sending above 150 chracter sms in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio, twilio-php

I am using [twilio library in codeigniter](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Twilio/blob/master/libraries/Twilio.php) . I am facing one issue the library does send the sms if its less than 150 character but as the number of character increased it don't send sms .

I searched on twilio website and figure out this

Yes. With the Messages resource URI, you can send messages containing up to 1600 characters. Learn about the Message functionality here. Note: the SMS resource URI is deprecated and does not support >160 characters.

Where as when i see the code of twilio library for codegnitor it has this function .

```
  public function sms($from, $to, $message)
    {
        $url = '/' . $this->api_version . '/Accounts/' . $this->account_sid . '/SMS/Messages';
        $data = array(
                    'From'   => $from,
                    'To'   => $to,
                    'Body' => $message,
        );
        if ($this->mode == 'sandbox')
            $data['From'] = $this->number;
        return $this->_twilio->request($url, 'POST', $data);
    }
```

and from the twilio website its using this

```
   /2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}
```

where as in twillio codeigniter library he has this

```
   '/' . $this->api_version . '/Accounts/' . $this->account_sid . '/SMS/Messages';
```

Is there a way that I can do changes and I can send more character using twillio Codeigniter library?

Comment: As a suggestion, could you just use the up to date Twilio PHP library within your application instead of this unsupported CodeIgniter version?

Comment: Guess he is using it because its 'CodeIgniter - Twilio library'. You can 
download official PHP Twilio library from here and use `include` https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install

Comment: Also I have tested Twilio PHP library and it is sending any length of SMS very fine. (Tested upto 3 SMS, it will be written in your log)

Answer (score 1):

ok a simple fix , You just need to change this line of code at line number 78 in libraries/Twilio.php file

```
          $url = '/' . $this->api_version . '/Accounts/' . $this->account_sid . '/SMS/Messages';
```

to this

```
          $url = '/' . $this->api_version . '/Accounts/' . $this->account_sid . '/Messages';
```